# Actor reprising his character in a totally unrelated film or series

Tags: character, acting

When was the first occurrence of an actor reprising his role as the same character in a **totally unrelated show or movie** like Bill Nye playing Patterson's father on Blindspot or Ursula Buffay appearing in Friends and Mad About You. Crossovers on the same franchise like Arrowverse and spin-offs are not counted.

Comment: Then that begs the question: wouldn't those 2 movies/shows be in the same universe if they share the same character? Hence they are not completely unrelated?

Comment: How can a film or series have the "same character" yet be "totally unrelated"?  What would that even mean?

Comment: The example I gave Bill Nye and his show is unelated to Blindspot yet his role as Patterson's father could be given any other name.

Answer (score 0):

Richard Belzer, a former stand-up comedian, played the character of Detective John Munch.

The character of John Munch, as portrayed by Belzer, began in 1993 on NBC's Homicide: Life on the Street, set in Baltimore.

In 1999, Homicide had a crossover with Law & Order. Later in that same year, Munch then joined Law & Order: Special Victims, as a regular character.

In the end, Belzer, as Munch, appeared on NBC's Homicide, Law & Order, Law & Order: SVU, [Law & Order: Trial by Jury](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0629766/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_12) and [30 Rock](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1635810/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_5). He also appeared (again, as Munch) in [Fox's Arrested Development](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0515215/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_10) and [The X-Files](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0751256/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_26); [UPN's The Beat](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0520391/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_17); [HBO's The Wire](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0306414/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_7); [NetFlix's Unbreakable Kimmy Schmidt](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4003750/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_3); and finally, on ABC's Jimmy Kimmel Live.